# Adding CLLocationCoordinate2D to custom MKAnnotation object

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation

I am very new to iOS, and even newer to using the MapKit library.

I am trying to create an instance of an MKAnnotation class called `TruckLocation`, and I have gotten this far but am really hung up on how to use my latitude and longitude as the coordinate.

The coordinates are lat 40.300828 and long -111.663802.

Here is what I have so far:

```
TruckLocation *a1 = [[TruckLocation alloc] initWithName:@"test truck 1" address:@"41 Truck Avenue, Provo, Utah" coordinate:<#(CLLocationCoordinate2D)#>];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need CLLocationCoordinate2D

make sure you include #import

then use something like this:

```
//note--CLLocationDegrees is just a double
CLLocationDegrees latitude = 40.300828;
CLLocationDegrees longitude = -111.663802;

CLLocationCoordinate2D yourLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

TruckLocation *a1 = [[TruckLocation alloc] initWithName:@"test truck 1" address:@"41 Truck Avenue, Provo, Utah" coordinate:yourLocation];
```